# State pattern: why states are not Singletons?

Tags: java, design-patterns, state-pattern

I've used the State pattern to implement a simple finite state machine. Looking at the description given on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern), and more specifically at the suggested Java implementation, I wondered why classes implementing the `State` interface (i.e. the various states) are not Singletons?

In the suggested implementation a new State is created whenever a transition occurs. However, one object is sufficient to represent each state. So, why wasting time creating a new instance every time a transition occurs?

Comment: I've run into the same problem in my project. I think if it is implemented as a singleton, then each `State` should have a `CleanUp` method to reset the signals or local vars. A little more complicated. So I'd rather `new` a instance each time. The target platform of my app is IOS, so performance may be a concern. But it works fine til now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because each state can store instance variables?

Take a look at the Wikipedia example you reference:

```
class StateB implements State { 
    private int count=0; 
    public void writeName(StateContext stateContext, String name) { 
        System.out.println(name.toUpperCase()); 
        if(++count>1) { 
            stateContext.setState(new StateA()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Can you see how it stores a count of the number of times it has been entered?

Now, in a FSM you probably want each state to be [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) (subsequent calls give the same feedback) but the State pattern is more general. One target use as described on the wikipedia page is:

> A clean way for an object to
>   partially change its type at runtime

As most objects probably use their local variables when performing actions, you would want the "changed type" version to use local variables as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your object has a state. Now what if you need "just one more whole thing like that"?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "assume your object has a state"? I have a finite state machine (FSM), which is a set of states. Each state does not change. The state of the FSM is simply it's current state (one of the available states). If the FSM changes, I must change either the transition logic, or the set of states (possibly by adding/removing some). In this context, I think each state can be a Singleton, can't it?

Comment: no, because when it's a singleton, you cannot have a clone of your whole state machine object with its state. Singleton = one per application.

Comment: Sure you can; a shallow clone would suffice since states aren't mutable and store no information beyond their identity.  Of course, if it's not a pure state-machine (i.e. states are annotated with non-static information).

Answer (score 1):

You may want a 'stateful-State' object (like demonstrated as [one example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern#Java) on the references wikipedia page) and in addition you may want to run several state machines of the same type in the same JVM.

This wouldn't be possible if each State was a Singleton.

Answer (score 1):

If your states don't need machine-specific additional state data, it makes perfect sense to reuse them across machines. That *doesn't* mean they are Singletons: Singletons also imply *global access* which you almost never want.

Here's a simple state machine that reuses states, but doesn't make them singletons.

```
public class SwitchState
{
    public SwitchState(bool isOn)
    {
        mIsOn = isOn;
    }

    public void InitToggleState(SwitchState state)
    {
        mToggleState = toggleState;
    }

    public bool IsOn { get { return mIsOn; } }
    public SwitchState Toggle() { return mToggleState; }

    private SwitchState mToggleState;
    private bool mIsOn;
}

public class LightSwitch
{
    public LightSwitch()
    {
        mState = sOnState;
    }

    public bool IsOn { get { return mState.IsOn; } }

    public void Toggle()
    {
        mState = mState.Toggle();
    }

    static LightSwitch()
    {
        sOnState = new SwitchState(true);
        sOffState = new SwitchState(false);

        sOnState.InitToggleState(sOffState);
        sOffState.InitToggleState(sOnState);
    }

    private static SwitchState sOnState;
    private static SwitchState sOffState;

    private SwitchState mState;
}
```

You can see there will only be a single on and off state in the entire application regardless of how many `LightSwitch` instances there are. At the same time, nothing outside of `LightSwitch` has access to the states, so they aren't singletons. This is a classic example of the Flyweight pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The question should be asked the other way around: why have `State` as a singleton? A singleton is only needed when you *require* global access and it is an **error** to have more than one instance.

It's certainly not an **error** to have more than one instance of a `State`, and you also do not *require* global access, so there is no need to make them singletons.

Comment: Making them "singletons" may have performance benefits, however.  If a state is not mutable and stores no per-instance information, then it's essentially just an enumeration value and comparison can occur by-reference - which is very quick - and instance creation/destruction is avoided (lowering GC load).

Comment: @Eamon Nerbonne: what you describe is exactly my case, and this is why I made my states singletons. However, I understand that in a general case this is not necessarily a good idea: see [Graphain answer above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090943/state-pattern-why-states-are-not-singletons/3090974#3090974).